# How can I make newly inserted records stay at the top of older records in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When I insert a new record in a database table it is displayed below older records in the table, and when I view the records in html, the new records goes down below

i.e

```
1  first inserted record
2  second inserted record
3  third inserted record
```

How can I make the new records that I insert in a database table to be displayed as the newest inserted record at the top of other records that I have inserted.

I want it displayed this way:

```
3  third inserted record 
2  second inserted record 
1  first inserted record
```

I'm using PHP MySQL Server version: 5.7.14

Could anyone guide me how can I achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: The order in which the records are stored is irrelevant. What matters is, how you order them while retrieving. Use `ORDER BY`  clause in your query to order the rows.

Comment: USE `DESC` wile fetching records  from table

Comment: in your SQL statement sort your data `ORDER BY ID DESC OR ASC` descending or ascending order

Comment: Thanks to you all, worked as expected

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE ORDER BY ID DESC;

Answer (score 0):

use can use you auto increment field as DESC.

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `order by` clause.

```
select *
from tableName
order by id desc;
```

you can replace `desc` with `asc` if you want to show in a sort order by insertion.

for more about `order by` http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-order-by/